# Would prepared statements and questions and requests be useful?

Tags: discussion

I like this site.
All of this may be wishful thinking.
Prepared statements are often more neutral and more accepted.

I have noticed some questions being put on hold for other new members.  I understand the desire for high signal to noise ratio.  Some new members, for valid reasons, are being put on hold. In the current manner, I could understand a new member feeling quite alienated. I find the yellow hold box a bit frigid.  I get a penalty impression from it.
I think that prepared statement could be more welcoming.

I know stack already has prepared statements and actions.
I understand questions may be edited.
Sometimes I think it might be useful for users to click on UI elements or
or have some suggested copy and paste or insert items or icons.
You can pick better wording. Delete or Add items.  This is just to have some standard comments for standard situations.

- I rate myself beginner, intermediate, advanced on this topic. Possible icon 3 bar position.
- I rate myself beginner, intermediate, advanced on Blender in general
- Please feel free to rephrase my question if that would expedite the answer process.
- Please feel free to point me to a tutorial for a very general question.
- I think I need a general tutorial.
- I am a newbie, and I am really making an effort, so be nice to me.  Or an Icon.

I think some newbies on Blender with general multiple topic questions could be more careful with their question. Everyone can be more careful.  I wonder if that does some harm. I do welcome newbies.  Most newbies can have a clear question.

All optional. Many for comment section only.  Not answer section.

- Could you provide a blender file?
- We suggest you search this site again. This question occurs frequently. Remember to vote a match up if it helps you.
- We understand your are a newbie, we can help.
- We have a tutorial to suggest to you on the general topic.
- This is not a beginner video tutorial site. We do not promote specific video sites.  Please see a video tutorial or other tutorial information of your choice and come back with specific a question.  We welcome your specific question.
- Please try to focus primarily on one topic. You will get more focused help.
- Please provide a screen image.  Click this link for more detail.
- Please be more clear and provide more detail
- The question is unclear so please rewrite.  You get more attention with a new question which is clear.

Removing some potential discomfort for those questions. Suggestions might be more neutral and kindly worded by consensus.

- You did not answer the question posed
- Blender does not offer that feature.  We have an alternative suggestion for you to consider.
- If we knew the larger technical picture of what you are doing we may be able to give alternative suggestions.
- This is not a direct answer to your question but we believe this information will be helpful.

I would be okay with clicking on 3 check boxes before submitting a question.

- I searched this site and could not find a great match
- I will check back within 24 hours to see if I have an answer
- I will show interest in my question by accepting an answer within 72 hours, or clicking the "I am still waiting for my perfect answer" button.

I understand Stack has some deletion policy.

Comment: As far as the search idea goes, stackexchange already searches based on the title of the new question. As far as the pre-written responses go, IMO it's better to write response which are specific to each question, perhaps explaining why it's off topic or where else they can look for answers. SE already has a few pre-written close reasons (which can be customized), see http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/296/599.